# Django rest token authentication

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, token

If I want to use both TokenAuthentication and SessionAuthentication, I get a CSRF error if it checks the session before the Token. Is this an indicator that something is wrong with my setup, or is this a shortcomming of DRF?

EDIT:
this works, but now everytime someone forgets the token I get an CSRF error.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

Comment: I use `djangorestframework-jwt` to avoid this problem

Comment: That one doesn't seem to support django 2.0

Comment: It does. I am using it.

Comment: pls check if You got `CSRF_USE_SESSIONS` set in You settings, when this option is set-off You must send CSRF with every request.

Comment: and remeber to have the `TokenAuthentication` before `SessionAuthentication` in views and to override in settings the DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES to have the `TokenAuthentication` at 1st place.

Comment: Can you give some context, example code, repo..?